# How to protect mcu pins from reverse voltage [edited]?

Tags: microcontroller, comparator

I am asked to build a 5 V /24 V circuit interface using an ATMEGA328P.For that i built a little comparator circuit to get  a 5 volt level on a I/O pin  .
My problem is that   the output of the comparator can be high while the I/O pin can be configured as a 5 volt output . 
  I thought a little then decided to add a 4.8 zener diode as below.[Edited]

Is this circuit safe to use?
[image]

Comment: Your diodes will block all current, so it won't work. What do you mean "the sensor using this circuit can be high while the pin is also high"?

Comment: Why is the pin configured as output? Why are you using a comparator; does the sensor output an analog signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R1 connected in series with the supply is not a good idea. The comparators can draw as much as 2mA (0.8mA typical) and you have zero common mode range to spare.

R8 also seems pointless- you will get only 2.5V signal from the comparator.

You can leave R2 in place, increase to 20K and replace D1 with a resistor as Kevin suggests (maybe 2K).

[image]

Comment: If  the Pins is configured as output and is outputing a low level does the 5 volt from the comparator sound risky for it?

Comment: No, it is just 5V thorough the pullup resistor from the comparator plus the series resistor.. so 22K in my example, and only 230uA. The comparator output is open-collector so it can only pull down.

Answer (score 0):

Since the comparator is an open collector output there is no problem if the output is high while connected to the MCU whose output is driving high.  There is a problem if the comparator is driving low and the MCU is driving high as there will be a conflict and a large current could flow.

I would remove r8 and replace D1 with a 10K resistor (value very non-critical could be 470 ohm - 22K).

Now if the comparator output and the MCU pin are in conflict the current will be limited to a safe level.

Comment: When i did so ,i have no more a 5 volt output when the comparator is high and MCU low.

Comment: Doesn't the pin marked 1 on your schematic go the MCU?   In that case I don't understand what you are attempting.  Can you describe more fully.  I thought you were interfacing a 24v signal into an MCU.